# Open Particular Excel Worksheet from Powerpoint via VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a Power Point presentation that contains data pasted into it from Excel using VBA. The data in the excel file is a table that contains hyperlinks to other worksheets within the same workbook. The VBA that creates this as an example is :

'Adds hyperlink to each worksheet user can use to find from powerpoint

```
Range("B2").Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'Title Missing'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Missing Title Tags"
```

This code works just fine - The Macro then pastes this table into Powerpoint. My problem is the file it is looking for via the powerpoint file is wrong, it is looking for a file called

```
C:\Users\Colin\Desktop\Title Missing.xlsx`
```

. "Title Missing" is the name of the worksheet and this path is the one being generated via the VBA despite the path working correctly from inside Excel when hopping from one worksheet to the other when clicking on the links the VBA creates.

How do I get the link to the right worksheet to work from within PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Address parameter:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
   Address:=ActiveSheet.Parent.FullName, _
   SubAddress:="'Title Missing'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Missing Title Tags"
```